# When extending TailwindCSS' theme, how can I include a new class that uses two drop-shadow() rules?

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, dropshadow

I'm creating a React App with TailwindCSS. I'm using the built-in `drop-shadow-md` utility class, which, in CSS, is equal to the following rule [as per the Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/drop-shadow):

```
filter: drop-shadow(0 4px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.07)) drop-shadow(0 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.06))
```

What I need to do is simply turn the y-offset values in both function calls ([the second argument for the `drop-shadow` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow())) to **negative values**, because I want to use the same computation to display a shadow on the **top** of a component (a navbar fixed to the bottom of the screen of a PWA).

So far I've  been able to extend my theme by adding a custom class `md-top`, but I can only add the first `drop-shadow()` call that the original `drop-shadow-md` class includes. I can't find the way to add the second `drop-shadow()` call.

This is the relevant part of my `tailwind.config.js` file:

```js
theme: {
    extend: {
      dropShadow: {
        'md-top': '0 -4px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.07)',
      }
    },
  },
```

How can I add that second function call in the Tailwind configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution is to register a plugin, as described in ([Tailwind's Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-utilities)).

In your `tailwind.config.js` file, in the plugins section, add this:

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin') // import Tailwind's 'plugin' function

module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {},
  plugins: [
    plugin(function ({ addUtilities }) {
      addUtilities({
        '.custom-shadow':
          { 'filter': 'drop-shadow(0 -4px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.07)) drop-shadow(0 -2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.06));' }
      }
      )
    }),
  ]
```

Then, in your jsx, it's accessible via the new class name `custom-shadow` like this:

```
<div className='custom-shadow' />
```

[Hovering in VScode shows the expected CSS output!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1y2y.png)